# Reading Script File Specifically C#

Tags: c#, find, cpu-word

So I have a Meta File that contains a long script partially shown below.
I only post here because I've noticed how quickly you guys reply & it's been bugging me for hours (literally) - I'm new

Example Script

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<CHandlingDataMgr>
  <HandlingData>
    <Item type="CHandlingData">
      <handlingName>Car1</handlingName>
      <fMass value="140000.000000" />
      <fInitialDragCoeff value="30.000000" />
      <fPercentSubmerged value="85.000000" />
      <vecCentreOfMassOffset x="0.000000" y="0.000000" z="0.000000" />
      <vecInertiaMultiplier x="1.000000" y="1.000000" z="1.000000" />

    </Item>
  </HandlingData>
</CHandlingDataMgr>
```

The output I want to gain is:

```
Car1, 140000.000000, 30.000000, 85.000000, "0.000000" "0.000000" "0.000000",  etc
```

(all values & names without scripted elements)`

Note: The above script occurs multiple times for different cars, all values also different.

I would also like for my friends to be able to replace my 'Cars.Meta' file with one of their own inside the same directory linked to my one if using same structure.

In a later version of my program I'd like for these cars to be listed with all their found data in a listBox. 
I've not found anything around the net regarding in-line word/number grabbing, I believe because of how specific the search is?
Thanks in advance for any help you can give :-)

Comment: Is your file going to be well formed xml?

Comment: Yes, the file contains well over 40 name's, with roughly 10 options regarding each

Comment: Can you post a bit more of the file? What's the full structure? Something like: `<people><person><name>Bob</name></person><person><name>John</name></person></people>`

Comment: Edited main post to include actual file, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is Parse or load your file into a suitable object which supports querying for the things you need. [`System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) is one such example.

Here's some code to start you off:

```
// xml is your Xml file as a string
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

// You could also load it from a file if you wanted
// var doc = XDocument.Load(fileLocation);


// You can now query the XDocument with Linq

// E.g. using fluent syntax
var items = doc.Descendants("HandlingData").Elements("Item");

// Or use the query expression syntax
var query = from i in items 
            select new { 
                HandlingName = (string)i.Element("handlingName"), 
                Mass = (decimal?)i.Element("fMass").Attribute("value") 
            };

Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", query.First().HandlingName, query.First().Mass);
// Prints: Car1 - 140000.000000
```

Have a look through the MSDN docs, and there are countless questions on SO about `XDocument`.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but XDocument cannot be found & XMLDocument does not contain a .Parse method

Comment: Make sure you have a reference for `System.Xml.Linq.dll` and that you have a `using System.Xml.Linq;` at the top of your file. What version of .Net are you using?